# Getting the last digits from string

Tags: php, regex

I have this string: tag:domain.com,2012-10-12:feed/channel/id/335

Im trying to get the last digits from this string into a variable. The date in this string is also dynamic, but I don't need that in a variable.

Here is my code:

```
$string = "tag:domain.com,2012-10-12:feed/channel/id/335";

preg_match(￼'/tag\:domain\.com,|\d+|-|\d+|-|\d+|\:feed\/channel\/id\/|\d+/', $string, $matches);


$last_digits = ???
```

Maybe there is an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
$aParts = explode('/', $string);
$iId = end($aParts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Use an anchor for the end of the string:

```
preg_match(￼'/\d+$/', $string, $matches);
```

(`$` represents the end of the string, or of a line in multi-line mode)

Then you can retrieve the ID like this:

```
$last_digits = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Ben Fransen code worked, but how would I get the variable using your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $string, $matches);
```

$ - means end

$matches[1] will have your value

Comment: yeap, what can I say, he is faster lol But I don't have ￼ in my code =P

Comment: @Furry Lol; use of all capital letters

Comment: Not in angry mode, but it shows my expression is being excited LOL

Comment: $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
$string = "tag:domain.com,2012-10-12:feed/channel/id/335";
$pattern = "/\/(\d+)$/";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

$number = $matches[1];
```

Basically, you ask for any digit that is between a `/` and the end of the string `$`.

Comment: What do you need the `i` modifier for?

Comment: Well actually nothing since there are no letters, case insensibility means nothing, just bad habits i guess. Editing.